# How many bookmarks do I have in Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

How can I see how many bookmarks I have in Firefox 4?

I have a number of bookmarks, which seems large to me. How do I get the exact number?

Comment: A low-tech solution would be to export the bookmarks as HTML, and count the number of relevant HTML elements in the resulting page (e.g. number of occurrences of `<A `).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many bookmarks do I have total in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/1024575/how-many-bookmarks-do-i-have-total-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this addon, featured by *[My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info)*: [**CheckPlaces**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10897/).

> sometimes it is quite messy especially you have a lot of bookmarks with some of them duplicated, broken links or links no longer valid. Now, there is a Firefox extension, named as CheckPlaces that can help you manage and clean up your bookmark in efficient way.

*Source:* http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/03/05/firefox-add-ons-cleanup-duplicate-and-invalid-bookmarks-with-checkplaces/

Notice at the top, under `Checked`, it has some statistics regarding your bookmark collection:
[image]

According to the CheckPlaces addon page at Mozilla Addons, it is compatible with Firefox Beta 4.

Comment: Looks interesting!

Comment: Wow! 2629 bookmarks.... I really should clean that up.

Comment: Since Firefox v57 these old non-WebExtension add-ons are unsupported and now also removed from AMO, As such, this answer does not work anymore.