# How many bookmarks do I have total in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I've just noticed that I have a lot of bookmarks and it's time to clean them up.

However, I want to be able to record how many bookmarks I have before and after the cleanup, to judge how effective it was.

**How can I find out how many bookmarks I have total, without counting them one by one?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Natively count all bookmarks in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/1194424/natively-count-all-bookmarks-in-firefox)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the bookmarks manager by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (thanks to rugk), or by clicking the all bookmarks button in the bookmarks menu, then select the 'All Bookmarks' folder.

In the top-right hand corner, search for a character which appears in all bookmarks, e.g. `.` or `/`.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all items. You can then see how many bookmarks you have total next to the 'items' indicator.

[image]

Comment: Does not work if one has defined a directory structure which means that using this method one would have to go directory by directory.

Answer (score 7):

Open Bookmarks Manager then go to Import and Backup. Hover over Restore and the flyout reveals how many bookmarks you have.

Comment: Wow, great. This is the actual solution and should actually be the accepted answer. It even shows you some chronological statistics!

Comment: That said, this seems to also count _folders_ and _tags_ (?), because it says "XY _entries". [Here is another solution](https://superuser.com/a/1194427/522670) (tl;dr: put `.` in the search)

Comment: This counts "items" to be backed up, not bookmarks. In addition to bookmarks, "items" includes the folders themselves that contain the bookmarks. Therefore, it's not a valid answer to the question since it doesn't actually count solely bookmarks, and results in an inflated number.