# Natively count all bookmarks in Firefox

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

This [question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1024575/how-many-bookmarks-do-i-have-total-in-firefox) describes how to find the total number of items in Firefox's *Bookmarks* menu, with the caveat that it only counts folders and files in the top-level directory - meaning that folders containing other files or folders will be counted as single items, resulting in a skewed bookmark count when you rely on folders to keep your bookmarks organised.

There are third-party Add-ons such as [Total Bookmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-gb/firefox/addon/total-bookmarks/?src=search) and [Bookmarks Manager and Viewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-gb/firefox/addon/bookmarks-manager-and-viewer/?src=search) that allow you to manage bookmarks, and probably offer more accurate bookmark counts as part of their functionality, but having to use a non-native Add-on for such a simple feature seems like a waste of resources, and I'd rather avoid it if I can.

**As of Firefox 52.0.2, is there a native way to view a count of *all* bookmarks?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many bookmarks do I have total in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/1024575/how-many-bookmarks-do-i-have-total-in-firefox)

Comment: That question was the very first link in my question, and the very premise that mine is based on. Maybe if you'd read the whole of my question, and how the answer to it differs from the one you consider it to be a duplicate of, you'd have been able to conclude for yourself that it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Oh sorry, did not see your first link. That said, actually, it is a dupe, because the _question_ asked for the same, only the _answer_ did not take folders into account. Actually [this answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1255995/522670) shows a possible solution to the same problem. And it does count all bookmarks from all folders.

Comment: @rugk That answer was posted months after I asked the question, which certainly wasn't a duplicate when I asked it and was very much needed because the only answer to the original question was incorrect. I'd maintain that this question still isn't a duplicate now, since the answer to it is still not documented in the other answer, though that's more open to debate.

Comment: Further, as you yourself have now realised, the solution you linked to counts "items", not bookmarks, and items include the folders themselves, so that answer isn't even a valid answer to the question - when I want a count of my bookmarks, I don't want to include the folders that they're in.

Comment: Well… that was likely not intended by the one who answered the question. And it is actually already a much better answer than only counting top-level bookmarks. All that said, this changes nothing from the fact that **the asked question** was and **is the same**. It would be good if these could somehow be merged… but I know, that's possibly not good nor possible. In any case, it is certainly **a dupe**.

Comment: The answerer's intentions make no difference - it's an invalid question whether they were aware of it or not. Yes, it's a better answer than counting top-level bookmarks, but if I considered counting top-level bookmarks to be an acceptable solution, I wouldn't have asked this question in the first place. The best and currently only valid solution to this problem was posted by @music2myear, and that was on this question - retroactively pretending that didn't happen because another question was asked earlier that now has two invalid answers, one from the asker himself, is idiotic.

Comment: You don't want to understand it, do you? **It's not about the answer** and we do not need to discuss the quality of the answer. **It is about the question.** Both questions are the same, both are dupes of each other. Users can "arrive" on each and should be able to find the best answer (here, admittingly). That's the basic concept of Stackexchange…

Comment: @rugk I'm afraid you're the only one that's having trouble understanding anything. You began this by not even bothering to check the first link of the question you marked as a duplicate, and it seems you're still intent on the gung-ho cowboy approach by fist-waving first and backtracking later. Duplicates on the Stack Exchange network are not dealt with purely in terms of chronology - *both* question and answer quality is taken into account. Do some reading: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651.

Comment: @rugk Your own reasoning lacks the most basic of coherence. You think users should be able to arrive at the best answer, and yet propose to close the question that you admit contains the best answer, and want to leave open the question that contains two invalid answers, purely because it was asked first. Once again, chronology is *not* the only thing taken into account for duplicates. Seriously - do less talking/typing, and more thinking.

Comment: Ah, this is your only concern. Well yeah, a closed answer is still visible, but one should possibly arrive at the best-formulated question or so. Don't know _which_ factors need to be considered there.

I don't care _which_ answer is closed, it should just be one answer that is open for this topic, and they should be properly cross-referenced… (As such, also marked the other as a dupe of this one.)

Comment: So then you'd better of voting for https://superuser.com/questions/1024575/how-many-bookmarks-do-i-have-total-in-firefox as a dupe of this one. Again, as said, I thought Stackexchange actually wants question just be closed as dupes of the first known question, i.e. time is what matters. But let the close votes decide…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, yes, you can.

Thanks to this Mozillazine article: https://kb.mozillazine.org/Counts_-_Counting_bookmarks_history_links_and_other_data_-_Firefox

Open the Bookmarks library by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> (that's the letter `oh`), then place ":" in the Search field to return all bookmarks.

You can now press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to get the total count.

Comment: Here is another solution: [Using the restore menu to count the bookmarks.](https://superuser.com/a/1255995/522670). Strangely though, both give me slightly different results… Maybe the restore menu only shows an "old" backup, from the same day, however. (no time included) Actually, I guess, however, it there also includes other "entries" like folders, possibly, as it is really a lot larger…