# Is there a maximum number of bookmarks in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I have the information in the back of my mind that Firefox had some sort of limit on how many bookmarks one could save?

AFAIK it deleted these afterwards, so the performance of the autocompletion (in the address bar/omnibar) would stay reasonable.
IIRC there was some similar (but lower?) limit for the Firefox history, but if that is deleted I obviously hardly care.

**How many bookmarks can be saved in Firefox? Is there an upper limit?**

The reason is I'd like to check how near I am this limit. After I found [one way](https://superuser.com/q/1194424/522670) or actually [two ways of counting all bookmarks in Firefox](https://superuser.com/a/1255995/522670).

Also: **What happens if I exceed this limit?** Is there some sort of warning? Does Firefox just delete old bookmarks?

So, do I have to fear Firefox could delete some bookmarks, if I use them too excessively?

---

Also asked/cross-posted at [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1256213).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bookmarks and history are stored in the SQLite database named `places.sqlite`.

As a database can grow as much as required, I don't think that there is really any limit.

(Note: If I myself haven't run out of bookmarks or history with my
3734 bookmarks and many thousands of history entries, you won't either.)

Answer (score 3):

No. I just did the trick for counting bookmarks (ctrl+shift+b, then searching for space or :, then ctrl+a) and I have over 6000. Though opening my bookmarks toolbar often lags for a second, there does not seem to be a hard limit.

Answer (score 1):

5,000

I hit this limit or whatever it used to be, there was some sort of warning so I exported on my bookmarks and only keep frequently visited URLs in bookmarks now.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-sync-troubleshooting-and-tips#w_my-bookmarks-arent-syncing-to-firefox-for-android

Comment: The maximum you indicated only applies to Firefox on the Android platform.  While the author did not indicate what platform they are using, we can only assume it isn't Android, due to the fact questions about Android platform are not within scope here at Super User.

Comment: Anyway, I think this is a good contribution since my question was not specific about any platform, having information for all platforms totally answers it. (and is good to know)

Comment: That said, this seems to be rather specific for Firefox Sync, so the answer would have been more appropriate [for this question](https://superuser.com/q/1440476/522670).

Comment: @Ramhound The limitation may be for Android but I believe (it was a long time ago) the limitation is applied equally to all platforms... I guess one could import 6k bookmarks and test if they were so inclined.