# Is there a maximum number of bookmarks or history for Firefox Sync?

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks, firefox-sync

This is a follow-up [of this question](https://superuser.com/q/1425094/522670). So there is no limit for saving bookmarks in Firefox, but is there actually a limit in Firefox Sync?

I have heard something like this.

And if so, does it mean I may loose some bookmarks when I sync them between devices? Or actually have some bookmarks only on some devices?

Same question for history entries etc.

Comment: see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1452358/522670) actually: Firefox for Android won't sync more than 5000 bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, actually the answer seems to be [on support.mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1244790):

> There is only a limit for the payload used for synced tabs and a date/time range for the history.
>   I don't think there is a limit for the bookmarks, but bookmarks are synced in chunks of a few hundred items (200), so it takes some time to sync a large amount of bookmarks.

So basically, it does not seem to be the case. It only takes some time and cannot sync hundreds of items at the same time.